# Infowindow on google map is not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am using google map api v3 with js and I am trying to to open infowndow on each marker on the map but through my code it is not opening here is my code sample please check it and tell me where is the error

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
 var map;

 var markers = new Array();

 function initialize() {
    var map_center = new google.maps.LatLng(31.2330555556,72.3330555556);


var GPS = <%=GPS %>
     var myOptions = {
      zoom: 8,
      scaleControl:true,
      pancontrol: true,
      streetViewControl: true,
      center: map_center,
      mapTypeControl: true,
      mapTypeControlOptions: {
      style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU
    },
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
    }    
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();


    for(i=0; i<GPS.length; i++)
    {

          var image = 'ico/no.png';

          var ContentString = GPS[i].TITLE;
          markers[i] = new google.maps.Marker(
          { 
           position: GPS[i].GPS,
           map: map,
           draggable:true,
           icon:image,
           title:GPS[i].TITLE
           });                      

            google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', function() {
            infowindow.setContent(ContentString);
            infowindow.open(map,markers[i]);
            });             
         }    
      }
</script>
```

Comment: Anyone please reply to my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(markers[i], 'click', function() { 
            infowindow.setContent(ContentString); 
            infowindow.open(map,this); 
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I have completed a program recently using the same api as yours. Facing to the same problem,I found the key factor is that the function of **addlistener** would work after the loop ended.It is said that the variable 'i' has reach to the maximizing value when the function of **addlistener** worked.So I have added a few steps to handle the problem. You can have a look at mine and I hope it is helpful for you.

```
function ShowParkingPoints() {

    var adNum=document.getElementById("tableOne").rows.length;
    var i;
    var j;
    var l;
    var ly;
    for (i=1;i<adNum;i++)
    {
        for(j=1;j<5;j++)
        {
            var k=i-1;

                addArray[k]+=document.getElementById("tableOne").rows[i].cells[j].innerHTML;
        }
    }
    for (i=0;i<adNum-1;i++){
            var image = new sogou.maps.MarkerImage('images/flag.png',
              new sogou.maps.Size(60, 60),
              new sogou.maps.Point(0,0),
              new sogou.maps.Point(0, 60));
            var shape = {
              coord: [1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18 , 1],
              type: 'poly'
          };

            geocoder.geocode( { 'address': addArray[i]}, function(results, status) {
              if (status == sogou.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                var str=results[0].formatted_address;
                //infowindow.setContent(str);
                 var marker1= new sogou.maps.Marker({
                    map: map,
                icon: image,
                    shape: shape,
                    draggable:true,  
                    position: results[0].geometry.location
                });
                 i=i-1
                 markerArrayS[i]=marker1;
                 locationArray[i]=results[0].geometry.location;
                  sogou.maps.event.addListener(markerArrayS[i], 'click', function(event) {
                    makerClicked(event.latLng);
            });
              } else {
                alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
              }
            });
    }
    map.setCenter(mapCenter);
            map.setZoom(13);

}
```

Comment: Can u tell me a bit idea to make cluster of markers in my above code

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to use 'i=i-1' to replace 'i' when you start to login event watcher.You can have a try. In a way,you need to notice that the order you storage in arrays when you want to read them out.